# Unity Inspector draw arrays with different names

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

It's possible to draw a serialized array in Inspector with custom name from it's property ("name")? (that will still have the expand triangle)

So instead of

-> Element 0

-> Element 1

it will be

-> Persons

-> Cars

having the classes like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Group {
   public string name;
   public Vector3 someVec;
}
public List <Group> m_Groups; // Drawing groups in the inspector
```

P.S. I'm going through each element with GetArrayElementAtIndex and draw individually

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

For each item in GetArrayElementAtIndex draw it with:

EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item, new GUIContent() { text = "New Title" });

where the "New Title" can be a property of current SerializedProperty which ca be got with property.stringValue

example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.arraySize; i++)
{
    SerializedProperty group = list.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
    SerializedProperty name = group.FindPropertyRelative("name");
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(group, new GUIContent() { text = name.stringValue });
    // Draw the subproperties...
}
```